# How to have a function calling sequentially other functions and emitting events?

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, generator, eventemitter

I don't know if this is duplicate, but I was not able to find an answer.

I am developing a Typescript library for a web application.
I need a function `f` that would need to sequentially call other functions and emit events to be listened by the caller.

Pseudocode:

```js
function f(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    const r1 = b()
    // wait for b execution
    emit('phase1', r1)
    const r2 = c()
    // wait for c execution
    emit('phase2', r2)
    const r3 = d()
    // wait for d execution
    emit('phase3', r3)
}
f('1', 3, '4').once('phase1', doSomething).once('phase3', somethingElse)
```

Using async/await would permit me to sequentially execute the inner functions, but in that case `f` would need to return a Promise, thus losing the possibility to emit events.
If I choose to return an event emitter I would lose in readability since inner functions could not be awaited sequentially.

I have found this interesting library [Promievent](https://github.com/naddison36/promievent), inspired by web3, but, since I think this is a not so rare application, I was wondering if there's a better approach/pattern to use.

Comment: What exactly do `doSomething` and `somethingElse` do? Do you care whether they are called in that order? Do you need to register them like "event listeners", are you settled on that `.once(…)` syntax?

Comment: @alain ... Regarding the so far provided answers / approaches are there any questions left?

Comment: Despite the good answers, I didn't find the generator approach desirable because of the iterator that needs to be called. I found the Promievent approach to better suit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

How about a [Generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) which yields events?  e.g.

```
function* f() {
    const r1 = b()
    yield ['phase1', r1]
    const r2 = c()
    yield ['phase2', r2]
}
```

Comment: This would require me to call `next()` at every step. Isn't it the case?

Comment: Generates implement both the iterator protocol (`next()`) as well the iterable protocol, so you can use a`for..of`loop.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested by *Josh Bothun* one could choose an approach based on [`generator functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) and [`generators`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator).

Since from what can be seen from the OP's provided pseudo code implementation of `function f(arg1, arg2, arg3) { /* ... */ }`, the asynchronous functions/methods might get provided as parameters to such a function. And since one needs to [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the result of each function call one has to go for an [async generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of#iterating_over_async_generators) approach which makes the OP's original `f` an asynchronous to be implemented function as well.

And as for the OP's concerns ...

> *"... but in that case `f` would need to return a [p]romise, thus losing the possibility to emit events"*

... of cause one can always emit/trigger/dispatch events from any asyn function. And the promise in witch such a function is wrapped/embedded into does neither always need to return a meaningful value nor does it always need to be handled (here e.g. by `await` ... see also the (unhandled) final invocation of the below provided async implementation).

```js
// an async function and event type generator-function.
async function* createAsyncFunctionAndEventTypeIterable(asyncFunctions) {
  let asyncFct;
  while (asyncFct = asyncFunctions.shift()) {

    yield (await asyncFct());
  }
}

// the OP's function which needs to be implemented as async.
async function awaitAndEmitOneAfterTheOther(...asyncFunctions) {
  // asyncFunctions = asyncFunctions.flat();

  const asyncIterable =
    createAsyncFunctionAndEventTypeIterable(asyncFunctions);

  for await (const [type, value] of asyncIterable) {
    emit(type, value);
  }
}


// test setup

// the event emitter mock.
function emit(type, value) {
  console.log('emit ...', { type, value });
}
function createAsyncTestFunctionAndEventType(delay, type, value) {
  return async function () {
    return await (
      new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay, [type, value]))
    );
  }
}
const [
  asyncFct_1,
  asyncFct_2,
  asyncFct_3,
] = [
  [2000, 'phase1', 'foo'], [1000, 'phase2', 'bar'], [3000, 'phase3', 'baz'],
].map(([delay, type, value]) =>
  createAsyncTestFunctionAndEventType(delay, type, value)
);

// execute test.
console.log('... test started ...');

awaitAndEmitOneAfterTheOther(asyncFct_1, asyncFct_2, asyncFct_3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```